# how to use route that is defined in another module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Trying to implement a new module (brought from another of my systems) in an already existing system. Not managing to define the route correctly.
Currently the dashboard routing, for example, is working - I would like the **Mycomponent** will also be routed.

The MyComponent is defined in MyModule module, not like the all other components which doesn't have their own module.
When I'm clicking on that route path:
path: '/**MyComponent**', title: 'My component',  icon: '', class: '' 
I'm getting the usual:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MyComponent'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MyComponent
Lets say that this is my files tree:

```
app\app.module.ts
app\app.routing.ts
app\dahshboard\dahshboard.component.ts

app\MyModule\MyModule-routing.module
app\MyModule\MyModule.module.ts
app\MyModule\MyComponent
```

This is the app.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes =[
{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: 'dashboard',
 pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
 path: '',
 component: LayoutComponent,
 children: [{
   path: '',
   loadChildren: './layout.module#LayoutModule'
  }]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  CommonModule,
  BrowserModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
   useHash: true
 })
],...
```

This is the sidebar.component.ts:

```
declare interface RouteInfo {
path: string;
title: string;
icon: string;
class: string;
}

export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [

{ path: '/MyComponent', title: 'My component',  icon: '', class: '' },
{ path: '/dashboard', title: 'Dashboard',  icon: 'dashboard', class: '' },
{ path: '/AAA', title: 'AAA',  icon:'AAA', class: '' },
```

This is MyModule.module.ts

```
import { MyModuleRoutingModule } from './MyModule-routing.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,      
    AppRoutingModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})
export class MyModule { }
```

This is MyModule-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'MyComponent',  component: MyComponent },
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyModuleRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add lazy load for myModule ,change your Routes to:
(if you are using angular ver 8 and up it's little bit different check documentation 
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

```
const routes: Routes =[
{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: 'dashboard',
 pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
 path: '',
 component: LayoutComponent,
 children: [{
   path: '',
   loadChildren: './layout.module#LayoutModule'
  }]
 },
 {
   path: 'MyComponent',
   loadChildren: './MyModule/mymodule.module#MyModule' 
 }

];
```